# pagination in jruby

Tags: jruby, will-paginate

I am using jruby, i want use pagination for my rails app

i used will_paginate but i think jruby does not support's for will_paginate.
 it gives error "undefined method `total_pages' "

```
in my units_controller.rb
 @units = Unit.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC')

and in views(index)
<%= will_paginate  @units%>
```

is there some other pagination gem which support jruby, because i  read in doc of will_paginate in that  it state that  will_paginate may support jruby not sure
plz help

Comment: Hi Harshal would you like to do freelancing in Jruby project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) and look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) for an introduction